# A different object with the same identifier value was already associated

Tags: hibernate, jpa

in my Java project, i have these three class and a code to insert data:

```
@Entity(name = "Quiz")
@Table(name = "quiz")
public class Quiz implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Skill skill;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentClass> stClasses= new ArrayList<>();


@Entity
public class Skill implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Student_Class")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class StudentClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "stClass_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Set<User> students=new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="stClasses", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Quiz> quizzes= new HashSet<>();

@Transactional
public void save(Quiz quiz) {
    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(quiz);
}
```

but if I insert a Quiz with a StudentClass that already uses a Skill I get this error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/AutoQuiz3000] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.Skill#10]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.Skill#10]] with root cause
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [fr.dawan.autoquiz3000.beans.Skill#10]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:648)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:284)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:227)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:92)
```

example:

```
quiz.setName("what the capital...");
quiz.setSkill("geography");
quiz.addstClass("formation Java");

quiz.setName("what the money...");
quiz.setSkill("geography");
quiz.addstClass("formation Java");
```

I have an error because the StudentClass is already using Skill! if I change the StudentClass I have not problem.

do not know how come the problem! someone an idea?

Thank you so much!

Comment: it might be helpful to use hibernateTemplate.evict(quiz); before hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(quiz);

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that because of the `Cascade.ALL` annotation, when you try to use `saveAndUpdate` or `persist`, this orders Hibernate to try and insert a new entity, which in your case, that entity already existed. So instead of using one of those methods, you need to merge your entity, which will check first, if it exists and then try to insert, otherwise it would simply do and update.

So you would need to do the following changes.

```
@Entity(name = "Quiz")
@Table(name = "quiz")
public class Quiz implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Skill skill;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<StudentClass> stClasses= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And on your repository, you would need to use `merge(entity)`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing 'orphanRemoval = true'-param from @OneToMany-annotation.